# is there anyway to display single column data into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sum, pivot

I tried to do it but it was impossible for me. the solution I need to display single column data into multiple column for the current table only. e.g column [status] 3 records `{present,late,absent}` to display 3 columns and single row, to prevent 3 rows

```
SELECT tid,status, COUNT(status) AS counter FROM `attend_teacher` GROUP BY status,tid ORDER by tid

+-----+---------+---------+
| tid | status  | counter |
+-----+---------+---------+
|   1 | absent  |       1 |
|   1 | present |       2 |
|   1 | late    |       1 |
|   3 | late    |       1 |
+-----+---------+---------+
```

**The result i want to display like this by grouping tid**

```
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
| tid | Present | late    | absent |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
|   1 |    2    |    1    |    1   |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
|   3 |    0    |    1    |    0   |
+-----+---------+---------+--------+
```

**Table structure**

```
SELECT * FROM `attend_teacher`;
+----+-----+----------+---------+---------+----------------+
| id | tid | day      | status  | subject | date_created   |
+----+-----+----------+---------+---------+----------------+
|  1 |   1 | Saturday | present | 1,5     | 8 May 2019     |
|  2 |   1 | Saturday | present | 1,1,5,2 | 8 October 2019 |
|  3 |   1 | Saturday | absent  | 1,1,5,2 | 9 October 2019 |
|  4 |   1 | Saturday | late    | 1,1,5,2 | 9 October 2019 |
|  5 |   3 | Saturday | late    | 1,3,5,4 | 9 October 2019 |
+----+-----+----------+---------+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: SQL Server != MySQL, please only tag the RDBMS you're actually using. Thanks.

Comment: *"Why I'm asking that the OP not tag an RDBMS that isn't related to the question"* some topicstarters might think adding more tags might get them help faster as the question is visible in more lists also the PHP and Javascript tags here also seams totally not needed..... anyhow @Larnu i am removing these chatty comments ;-)  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to pivot the dataset:

```
select
    tid,
    sum(case when status = 'present' then 1 else 0 end) present,
    sum(case when status = 'late' then 1 else 0 end) late,
    sum(case when status = 'absent ' then 1 else 0 end) absent 
from attend_teacher
group by tid
```

Comment: Thanks for your help in solving this problem

Comment: If it answered the question, @Keynan, consider accepting it as the solution.