# How to get the values of same I'd into different columns into a single row

Tags: sql

I have 2 values for same I'd. I need to get the 2 values in the different columns in a single row

Comment: Please include some rows of your table in the question.

Comment: search for "pivot" or "conditional aggregation" many examples available. eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58473261/is-there-anyway-to-display-single-column-data-into-multiple-columns/58473278#58473278 
PLUS **please** when asking questions don't just use the tag "sql" - every database vendor has variations in their implementation of sql - so to help you we really need to know what database you use (e.g. mysql, postgres, sql server, oracle etc.) use the **Edit tags** link to add tags

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your RDBMS has the `PIVOT` statement, maybe that would be the best way.

If you want a query that works on any RDBMS, I would recommend to use `CASE WHEN`.

There isn't a best way to do this dynamically in a SQL `SELECT` query. If you need transpose dynamically, try to do that in Python or another programming language that isn't declarative like SQL.